# Can't use and connect to MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

So, I am building a small URL shortener project with js, express, and MongoDB but, I got errors when I'm trying to run my local server and I can't connect to MongoDB!
This is my code:

```
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const ShortUrl = require('./models/shortUrl')
const app = express();

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/urlShortener', {
useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true
})

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false}))

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
const shortUrls = await ShortUrl.find()
res.render('index', { shortUrls: shortUrls })
});

app.post('/shortUrls', async (req, res) => {
await ShortUrl.create({ full: req.body.fullUrl })

res.redirect('/')
})

app.get('/:shortUrl', async (req, res) => {
const shortUrl = await ShortUrl.findOne({ short: req.params.shortUrl })
if (shortUrl == null) return res.sendStatus(404)

shortUrl.clicks++
shortUrl.save()

res.redirect(shortUrl.full)
})


app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
```

And this is the full log:

```
[nodemon] 2.0.15
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
C:\Users\apsoltanian-pc\Documents\js\url-shortener\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:807
  const serverSelectionError = new ServerSelectionError();
                               ^

MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (C:\Users\apsoltanian-pc\Documents\js\url-shortener\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:807:32)
    at C:\Users\apsoltanian-pc\Documents\js\url-shortener\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:342:10
    at C:\Users\apsoltanian-pc\Documents\js\url-shortener\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:32:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\apsoltanian-pc\Documents\js\url-shortener\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\apsoltanian-pc\Documents\js\url-shortener\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1176:10)   
    at Mongoose.connect (C:\Users\apsoltanian-pc\Documents\js\url-shortener\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:341:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\apsoltanian-pc\Documents\js\url-shortener\server.js:6:10)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1099:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) {
      'localhost:27017' => ServerDescription {
        _hostAddress: HostAddress { isIPv6: false, host: 'localhost', port: 27017 },
        address: 'localhost:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 1096791,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
            at connectionFailureError (C:\Users\apsoltanian-pc\Documents\js\url-shortener\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:381:20)
            at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\apsoltanian-pc\Documents\js\url-shortener\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:301:22)
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:642:26)
            at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:164:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:129:3)
            at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
      }
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined
  }
}

Node.js v17.7.2
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Thank u guys =)

I was trying to start the small URL-shortener project that I wrote in js, express, and MongoDB but, the problem is that I can't connect to my MongoDB database :(

Comment: You can include the code for the database connection, in your post (so that someone can take a look and tell what is the issue with it). Is your database server up and running?

Comment: Hi! yes my db and server are running.

Comment: I edited the text and put the code

Comment: See this: https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.4/reference/connection-string/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, so, I replaced localhost with 127.0.0.1 in the connection string and now my problem is solved!
it is because of some ipv6 configurations...
Thank u :)